# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA run all the tests including sub packages

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, scalatest

If I click on a package and do control-shift-F10, it failed with this error:

```
Error running ScalaTests in 'tests': Not found suite class.
```

And when open test configuration i see the the "Test Package" is

> src.main.scala.com.myproject.pro.integration.tests

And when i change it to be:

> com.myproject.pro.integration.tests

it just run the tests that existing in the first level without running the sub packages tests.

my configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

1- Mark the parent folder as "Test Sources Root"
[image]

2- Click on your suite and click on control-shift-F10

3- Run the tests